# lxml installation fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, pip, lxml

I am trying to install `lxml` python module:

```
sudo pip3 install lxml
```

Previously i used:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

I get this output (hangs for a few minutes before fail) - ending:

```
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-67svy8ob-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Installed successfully on my local machine, fails on VPS.

Comment: `apt-get install python3-lxml` is solution, installed fine. But i still don't understand why installation from source fails.

Comment: The error message suggests you lack zlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/627149/56648) worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-pip
sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: What version of ubuntu you use?

Comment: Ubuntu version: 14.04.3

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. It's a one-shot installation for everything, guaranteed. Just go to the LXML section, and choose the right whl file for your machine and Python type (they have 32 bit and 64 bit, Python 2.6 to latest, even beta 3.5!). Pip install the wheel and you're done.

Comment: The problem is that those binaries are for Windows platform and the question is for Ubuntu